# "Would you like to go on a holiday together?" -- is this correct English?

Tags: phrases, informal-language

One person asks another person:

> Would you like to go on a holiday together?

or

> Would you like to go out together?

I take it that "with me" or "with us" is implied.

Is that use of "together" (with a singular subject and without "with so.") correct English? Is it slang? Regional? Or not correct at all?

I tried to find this on Google, there are definitely examples of use, but not a lot, which could be due to the fact that it's not a sentence that you would normally write on a website.

One example I found was a song called "Do you want to die together?", and an entry in the jargon dictionary, but I'm still not sure if this is a common or correct way to put it.

To clarify, I'm not looking for better ways to say this, I have heard this and I'm asking if this way to put it would be considered correct and in use, or if it's incorrect or slang.

Comment: You could say "Do you want **us** to go on holiday (or out) together?", but it is more usual to say "Do you want to go on holiday (or out) **with me**?"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Thanks! So I understand that my examples don't sound natural/idiomatic?

Comment: You understand correctly.

Comment: Or even _Shall we go together?_ which seems natural to me as well as @MichaelHarvey suggestions. I do not think your options were wrong but they did not sound quite right either.

Comment: I would only use *together* when the you and the other person already had independent ideas about going to the same place, "I just heard you're also going to Mary's party this weekend. Do you want to **go together**?"